# elasticsearch 7 is in YELLOW state with unassigned shard

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I'm unable to get cluster of single master node in working green condition:
elasticsearch: 7.17.0

I guess that is because I have **unassigned_shards** > 0

#### config:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  elasticsearch.yml: |-
    discovery:
      type: single-node
    network:
      host: 0.0.0.0
    path:
      data: /bitnami/elasticsearch/data
    xpack:
      ml:
        enabled: false
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: elasticsearch
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: elasticsearch
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: elasticsearch
    helm.sh/chart: elasticsearch-19.5.5
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: elasticsearch
```

```bash
kubectl logs elasticsearch-master-0

[2022-12-25T07:52:40,652][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [elasticsearch-master-0] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.10.28-000014][0], [.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.09.28-000012][0]]]).
[2022-12-25T07:52:40,856][INFO ][o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  ] [elasticsearch-master-0] updating geoip database [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]

✗  curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health\?pretty\=true
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 7,
  "active_shards" : 7,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 1,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 87.5
}

➜ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards                                                                                         
magento2_product_1_v583                                       0 p STARTED    4868 18.9mb 10.110.4.229 elasticsearch-master-0
.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.10.28-000014                           0 p STARTED                10.110.4.229 elasticsearch-master-0
.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.11.27-000015                           0 p STARTED                10.110.4.229 elasticsearch-master-0
.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.08.29-000010                           0 p STARTED                10.110.4.229 elasticsearch-master-0
.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.09.28-000012                           0 p STARTED                10.110.4.229 elasticsearch-master-0
.geoip_databases                                              0 p STARTED      40 38.1mb 10.110.4.229 elasticsearch-master-0
.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.12.21-000022 0 p STARTED                10.110.4.229 elasticsearch-master-0
.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.12.21-000022 0 r UNASSIGNED
```

I'm trying to delete it but facing an error

```bash
➜ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards | grep UNASSIGNED | awk {'print $1'} | xargs -i curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/{}"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   986  100   986    0     0   5241      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5244
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"index [.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.12.21-000022] is the write index for data stream [.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default] and cannot be deleted"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"index [.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.12.21-000022] is the write index for data stream [.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default] and cannot be deleted"},"status":400}
```

**GET /_cluster/allocation/explain**:

```
➜ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain\?pretty\=true | jq
{
  "note": "No shard was specified in the explain API request, so this response explains a randomly chosen unassigned shard. There may be other unassigned shards in this cluster which cannot be assigned for different reasons. It may not be possible to assign this shard until one of the other shards is assigned correctly. To explain the allocation of other shards (whether assigned or unassigned) you must specify the target shard in the request to this API.",
  "index": ".ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.12.21-000022",
  "shard": 0,
  "primary": false,
  "current_state": "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info": {
    "reason": "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
    "at": "2022-12-25T07:52:37.022Z",
    "last_allocation_status": "no_attempt"
  },
  "can_allocate": "no",
  "allocate_explanation": "cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
  "node_allocation_decisions": [
    {
      "node_id": "aURccTcnSuqPC3fBfmezCg",
      "node_name": "elasticsearch-master-0",
      "transport_address": "10.110.4.229:9300",
      "node_attributes": {
        "xpack.installed": "true",
        "transform.node": "true"
      },
      "node_decision": "no",
      "deciders": [
        {
          "decider": "same_shard",
          "decision": "NO",
          "explanation": "a copy of this shard is already allocated to this node [[.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2022.12.21-000022][0], node[aURccTcnSuqPC3fBfmezCg], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=tsxhnODlSn-i__-vEvJj3A]]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

#### So what can be done in such scenario?

```bash
curl -v -XPUT "localhost:9200/*/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "index" : {
    "number_of_replicas" : 0
  }
}
'

{"acknowledged":true}


curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices     
green open magento2_product_1_v583 hvYpUxJUT16-g6_YS8qkaA 1 0 4868  0 18.9mb 18.9mb
green open .geoip_databases        tDXBLQRdSFeQyi6Pk5zq2Q 1 0   40 40 38.1mb 38.1mb
```

Answer (score 0):

Yellow status indicates that one or more of the replica shards on the Elasticsearch cluster are not allocated to a node. When you have only one node, it means your number of replicas is greater than your number of nodes. Elasticsearch will never assign a replica to the same node as the primary shard. so, if you only have one node it is perfectly normal and expected for your cluster to indicate yellow. But, if you are not convinced and want your cluster to be green, set the number of replicas to each index to be 0.

```
PUT /my-index/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried (see my commands above), but it didn't help. Same state after running them.

Comment: Looks like 7.16 adds a new stream/index for deprecation logging. However, it is created with "number_of_replicas": "1" and you only have one node, so it's always yellow.

Try reconfiguring the index template for it.

Check this out - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/configure-deprecation-log-index-properties/291342/10